# How to use Where operator in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
SomeObject.Where(p => FunctionOn(p.I));
<<>>
public bool FunctionOn(int i){
    return (i == 1);}
<<>>
error message : The method FunctionOn is not supported
```

but why when I use number instead of parameter it works fine ?

```
SomeObject.Where(p => FunctionOn(1));
```

I was wondering if there is a way to implement this code in Linq , because it gives me an error . 
 Thank you .

Comment: What error do you get? `FunctionOn` should return `bool`.

Comment: yes it is , an error like this method not supported or something like that . (that I can't use it)

Comment: Compilation error or Runtime exception?

Comment: @Rawhi Can you please provide the exact error message and the signature of the `FunctionOn` method. Thanks.

Comment: @Rawhi Could you also detail what you expect the code to actually do.

Comment: @Rawhi What type is `SomeObject`?

Comment: Iqueryable collection . aslo I put the result into gridview , if that could help

Comment: Are we talking about LINQ to Objects or LINQ to SQL here?

Comment: I'm actually using LINQ to MongoDB. which is not LINQ to SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> SomeObject.Where(p => FunctionOn(p.I));
> ```

You said that `SomeObject` is an `IQueryable`. This makes me suspect that you aren't querying an in-memory collection (LINQ-to-Objects), where your query should succeed without any problems, but you're possibly querying something more "dynamic". For the sake of demonstrating the problem, I will assume that we're dealing with LINQ-to-SQL here... but that assumption doesn't have to be necessarily true for what I would like to explain below:

> ***Update:** You've just said in a comment that you're using LINQ-to-MongoDB, so the below should apply to your issue.*

With something like LINQ-to-SQL, the problem with your query isn't that something's wrong with the `FunctionOn` predicate method, or with the way you're combining it with the `Where` operator. The problem at hand is that LINQ-to-SQL (or whatever LINQ provider you're using) doesn't recognise your method. It's trying to convert your LINQ expression into an SQL query at runtime (that's exactly what `IQueryable` is good for, after all!), but it doesn't know how to convert your `FunctionOn` to SQL.

If LINQ-to-SQL were to achieve this, it would have to figure out what your method is doing, and then find a way to express that as valid SQL. That would take a lot of sophistication and intelligence. For example, it would have to inspect your method e.g. by decompiling it, and then re-compiling it as SQL. This clearly cannot work for any arbitrarily complex method. Imagine that your `FunctionOn` method contained a call to `Debug.WriteLine`. There's no way that this could be translated into an SQL query.

Thus LINQ-to-SQL is restricted to a few cases and expressions that it knows how to handle. If it encounters anything else in a LINQ expression, it'll let you know that it doesn't know how to handle `FunctionOn` (ie. how to convert it to SQL) by saying something like, *"The method FunctionOn is not supported."*

Once you write your query as:

```
SomeObject.Where(p => p.I == 1);
```

everything should work fine, since LINQ-to-SQL knows how to translate your `p.I == 1` to a corresponding equality test in a SQL `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I know but if I need to do something more complex than this , something like a function which check if the p.Id is Exists in a List or not . BTW if use any number 1,2..etc instead of sending a parameter its works fine then !! explanation !? (p => FunctionOn(1))

Comment: +1 Good answer! Many people don't understand the diff between IQueryable & IEnumerable! =P

Comment: @Rawhi It would probably just take the value of `FunctionOn(1)` once and then place it into the expression, the function will never get called while the expression is running.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be more specific with the error you are actually getting, however, as a general guide normally this would fail if `FunctionOn` cannot be translated into a database specific language query (if SomeObject is a DB entity) or it does not return a boolean value which the `Where` function expects.

Comment: @Rawhi - LINQ will try to convert your `FunctionOn` function to T-SQL which will fail because it can't access the expression tree as the code is compiled. See http://tomasp.net/blog/linq-expand.aspx for more information on why your code won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This might work, Try :

```
SomeObject.AsEnumerable().Where(p => FunctionOn(p.I))
```

It would work for Linq-To-Entities and Linq-To-SQL too!

Why! How?

Because like **stakx** explains. `IQueryable` stores your expression. If you check out the [docs for IQueryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx) it has an [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.expression.aspx) property, this *stores* the Linq you write in your code, and then a LinqProvider then translates it into the right thing, in your case that would be **MongoDB syntax/SQL** IDK? For linq-to-sql this would turn into an T-SQL expression. So there is no *SQL-way* to write `FunctionOn()`. Can it magically call your function written in C# from SQL? Nope!

Now, `IEnumerable` is an object collection in memory. When you say AsEnumerable() you get **the objects in memory**, then when you do `Where(x=> func(x))` Linq-To-Objects can handle it no problem.

Like @Will on the comments rightly says, this gets **every single object into memory** and then queries it. At times it may not be what you want to do, but I wanted you to understand **why** your code doesn't work and also if you **needed** there is sorta a *workaround*

Hope it gave you the same insight I discovered a few weeks ago while watching lots of channel9 Linq Videos. =)

Comment: While this may 'work', it will result in pulling down EVERY SINGLE OBJECT from your data source, and doing the comparison locally. This will work up to a certain size, and will either get progressively slower, or your datasource may even refuse to cooperate.  A better solution is instead to return an expression.

Comment: Yes thats true! Sorry, I will make that clearer, I just wanted to explain to the OP the difference and WHY his code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, your `FunctionOn` method isn't directly translatable by your data source.

However, there may be a way around it - depending upon what sort of comparison you need to do, and how big of a comparison you're making.

If instead, you create an extension method which takes an `IQueryable<T>` and returns `IQueryable<T>` you can write your expression directly.

This allows you to re-use complex expressions. You should also be able to compare against a list of reference data - however you'll need to take care that this comparison list doesn't exceed the parameters permitted for your datasource.

Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{


    var data = new List<Customer>
                {
                    new Customer {Id = 1, Name = "Anna"},
                    new Customer {Id = 2, Name = "Bob"},
                    new Customer {Id = 3, Name = "Claire"}
                };



    var result = data.AsQueryable().TestCustomer();




}

private static IQueryable<Customer> TestCustomer(this IQueryable<Customer> source)
{
    return source.Where(x => x.Id > 1);
}


public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```